# How to reopen custombox correctly?

Tags: jquery

[Custombox](http://dixso.github.io/custombox/)
Given the following codes, I can open the #dialog by calling openCommandDialog at first time, however, an error is occurred after calling the method at second time. I was wondering if there is any correct way to open the dialog.

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined
    at Object.c.set (http://localhost:58139/Scripts/custombox/custombox.min.js:10:1283)
    at Object.open (http://localhost:58139/Scripts/custombox/custombox.min.js:10:14706)
    at <anonymous>:2:11
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:905:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:838:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)c.set @ custombox.min.js:10open @ custombox.min.js:10(anonymous function) @ VM312:2InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ VM267:905InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ VM267:838InjectedScript.evaluate @ VM267:694
```

Code:

```
function openCommonDialog() {
    $(function () {
        Custombox.open({
            target: '#dialog',
            effect: 'slide',
            overlayEffect: 'fadein',
            overlayClose: false,
            animation: ['bottom', 'top'],
            position: ['center', 'center'],
            speed: 250
        });
    });
}
```